# Laravel access constant with in constant

Tags: arrays, laravel, constants

I have defined constant in Laravel as below

```
class urlConstants
{
const url_01= [ 'id' => 1 , 'text' => 'xxxxxx' ] ; 
const url_02= [ 'id' => 2 , 'text' => 'bbbbbb' ] ; 
..
const url_99= [ 'id' => 99 , 'text' => 'ccccc' ] ; 
}
```

Now what I wants to do is define new array within urlConstants which include another array like below

```
 class urlConstants
    {
    const url_01= [ 'id' => 1 , 'text' => 'xxxxxx' ] ; 
    const url_02= [ 'id' => 2 , 'text' => 'bbbbbb' ] ; 
    ..
    const url_99= [ 'id' => 99 , 'text' => 'ccccc' ] ;

     // I KNOW I CAN DO SOMETHING LIKE BELOW
    const commonArray = [ 1 , 2 , 99 ]; 
    //
    }
```

But I wants to know that is there is any other way to access this variable rather than just typing the integers like below

```
 class urlConstants
    {
    const url_01= [ 'id' => 1 , 'text' => 'xxxxxx' ] ; 
    const url_02= [ 'id' => 2 , 'text' => 'bbbbbb' ] ; 
    ..
    const url_99= [ 'id' => 99 , 'text' => 'ccccc' ] ;

     // 
    const commonArray = [ url_01['id'] , url_01['id'] , url_01['id'] ]; 
    //
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to defined constant `commonArray`, you can **defined a static method**,

and **call other constants** by [constant()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```php
public static function commonArray() {
    $common_array = array();
    $nums = range(1, 99);
    foreach($nums as $n) {
        $const_name = 'self::url_'. str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // this will return self::url_01, self::url_02,...
        $common_array []= constant($const_name)['id']; // call the const url_01, url_02...
    }
    return $common_array;    
}
```

So you can call this commonArray by:

```php
urlConstants::commonArray();
```